# Are separate controllers used when adopting full scale CQRS?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I understand there are three flavours of CQRS:

```
1) Separate models only i.e. a domain model and a read model.
2) separate models and repositories.
3) Separate models; repositories and physical database.
```

Is there ever a scenario where the controllers are separated into read controllers and write controllers? I have never seen this, however I am sure I once saw a diagram, which indicated separate read and write controllers.

I realise that the application will still work in the same way regardless of whether the controllers are separated.  I am asking from the perspective of the principle of least astonishment.

Answer (score 2):

```
1) Separate models only i.e. a domain model and a read model.
```

I think you mean command model and query model. This is typical of [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html):

[image]

```
2) separate models and repositories.
```

Typically goes by the name [microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).

[image]

```
3) Separate models; repositories and physical database.
```

Separating the DBs is an implementation choice. It has no logical impact. It simply makes the separation obvious and helps ensure they continue to be separated.

> Is there ever a scenario where the controllers are separated into read controllers and write controllers?

You can do this. It helps ensure the models stay in their lanes. But it's not required in typical CQRS. If you want to make a case that it's surprising do an image search for [CQRS controlers](https://www.google.com/search?q=CQRS+controllers&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS752US752&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT46vs9urhAhVsx1kKHeVAB2sQ_AUIDygC&biw=1200&bih=1974#imgrc=2V_woY_SDo-poM:). So far I've counted 10 diagrams that show one controller running both the query and command models without finding one diagram that showed separate controllers.

What you don't do is separate into a query DB and a command DB because that means you can never read what you wrote. You can have a DB that an app only ever queries. But if nothing ever sends commands to it you're not going to find much there.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the last paragraph? I have seen implementations of single micro services that have separate databases for read and write that use a message queue.

Comment: +1 for the diagrams.

Comment: Thanks.  The answer was helpful.  However, the diagrams don't indicate whether the same controllers are used for read and write.  Do you know any source that references controllers in a CQRS implementation?

Comment: @w0051977 better?

Comment: Thanks.  Is it fair to say that it is unusual to separate the controllers?

Comment: @w0051977 According to the image search that I linked it's at least hard to find diagrams that depict that.

Comment: Whether to use one controller, two, or more isn't an aspect of CQRS. It would be awful design, but you could have every single command and query supported by your application in a single controller. You could have every command and every query in its own controller.

Comment: FWIW I would not rely on the frequency of diagrams returned by a Google search to indicate anything. I'd always lean toward smaller classes that do fewer things, but the purpose of the controller is largely just to pass requests to handlers. So this doesn't seem like it's worth overthinking. You can always change your mind.